# React Firebase Sign In With Google

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to sign in with google in my react app using firebase
The Popup window only shows up on the mobile but does not add the user to the firebase users list
While the popup window which comes on the browser is blank.
It also works on a mobile screen selected from the dev tools of any web browser.

The below is my firebase config file

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

const configg = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(configg);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
console.log("firebase file");
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

Comment: Add the error if any in console

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use customOAuthParameters?

```
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account'});
```

For more possible parameters you can check out https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#authenticationuriparameters

Comment: Yes i did, also to update when i select an account on the popup window it shows a loading sign and then the window closes and when i go backt o the firebase console to see if the user was registered it shows no user.